# You cant view this page because you don't have permission or because the page isn't supported on mobile devices Salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app, process-builder, chatter, chatter-feed, sales

I have a process builder which does a chatter posts on a user's home page upon satisfying some conditions. The chatter posts consists of a link also which upon clicking re-direct the user to the record.It is working fine when in desktop browser but when same is trying in mobile app SF1 receiving below errors:
'You cant view this page because you don't have permission or because the page isn't supported on mobile devices Salesforce'

[image]

[image]

I have dome some research but couldn't able to figure out the way to rectify the same.

Kindly help me.

Many thanks in advance

Thanks & Regards,
Harjeet

Comment: Is it a custom VF page?

Comment: No @Tushar Sharma

Comment: No @TusharSharma

Comment: The link is actually a Task/Event record link.When clicks on the same it will open corresponding Task/Event record link

Comment: Then check the URL. You are adding extra ` \  ` there.

Comment: Thanks @TusharSharma for your response. My question is when the link is opening succesfully in web browser then why not it opens up in SF1

Comment: @TusharSharma     Also you may be aware that we can't create hyperlink in chater post using process builder. So I created one custom field on Activities which dynamically pulls login sandbox url and then re-direct user to corresponding Task/Events records. The field which I have created is of a formula field return text Formula(text) and formula is LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_300, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_300)). Then in process builder I am referring link as Link: {![Event].Fetch_URL_Dynamically__c}/{![Event].Id}

Comment: Thanks @TusharSharma.You were spot on. Your opinion worked and saves lots of time for me. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your URL you have one extra `\`. Remove that and it will work. The reason is Web browser can handle the extra \ but not the SF app. So you need to be careful here.